# Magic Trackpad 2 - Can't connect through Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, magic-trackpad

My Magic Trackpad 2 can't connect via Bluetooth with my MacBook Pro 2014.

The trackpad works fine when connected via cable, but when I unplug it, I can't get the Bluetooth to kick in. I've tried restarting my laptop, resetting the Bluetooth module, clearing my laptop's NVRAM, using different USB ports, and a bunch of different connect/off/on combinations with the bluetooth, cable, and trackpad, but nothing's working. Apple support didn't help and I can't factory reset the trackpad itself through Bluetooth since it won't connect through Bluetooth in the first place.

I'm running macOS 10.15.7 and my Bluetooth v 7.0.6f8. Other Bluetooth accessories connect perfectly fine to my laptop.

I don't have access to another Apple computer to test whether it's my laptop or the trackpad itself.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: You say you don't have access to another Apple computer to test — do you have access to a non-Apple computer? It should work with Windows too.